# Is any convergent subsequence of a bounded sequence of L2 functions uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I think this is a relatively straight-forward question. It is part of a larger proof that I am trying to do.

If I have an arbitrary, bounded sequence of functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is any convergent subsequence of this bounded sequence uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take a sequence of continuous functions that converge pointwise to a discontinuous function in a suitable way. E.g. (specialising to $L^2([0,1])$) we can use the sequence of $f_n$s whose graphs consist of three line segments: from $(0,0)$ to $(\frac12,0)$, from $(\frac12,0)$ to $(\frac12+\frac1{2n},1)$, and from $(\frac12+\frac1{2n},1)$ to $(1,1)$.